# Remove marker from Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map where I want to add a marker (with info window) via a checkbox. It also works quite well, but I just can not get it deleted again when I uncheck the checkbox. Can anyone help?

See also here: http://jsfiddle.net/x8D7y/

```
function clearOverlays() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker300, 'click');
}

function showOverlays() {
    var marker300 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0, 1.0),
        map: map /*,
        icon: 'img/bike5.png' */
    });

    var infowindow300 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div style="width: 200px;">Test 300 - <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a></div>'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker300, 'click', function() {
        infowindow300.open(map, marker300);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you got the correct answer, mark it as correct, in order to save tie from other members in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an external Array which holds the extra markers you use with the map. In your case I have added the following array:

```
var extraMarkers = [];
```

Then when I click the checkbox, I am getting the ID of that checkbox, and send it in both `showOverlays()` and `clearOverlays()` as function argument.

Then, in `showOverlays()`, I am using the checkbox `ID` as extraMarkers key and the marker as value.

Finally, in `clearOverlays()` I use again the checkbox `ID` to get the element with this ID from the extraMarkers array and I see the map to `null`, in order to remove the marker.

See here the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/x8D7y/1/

Here is the full code required by you:

```
var map;
var extraMarkers = [];
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0, 1.0)
};

map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.5, 1.5),
        map: map /*,
        icon: 'img/bike5.png' */
    }
);

var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
        content: '<div style="width: 200px;">Test 1 - <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a></div>'
    }
);

google.maps.event.addListener(
    marker1, 
    'click', 
    function()
    {
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
    }
);

function clearOverlays(myID)
{
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(extraMarkers[myID], 'click');
    extraMarkers[myID].setMap(null);
}

function showOverlays(myID)
{
    var marker300 = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.0, 1.0),
            map: map /*,
            icon: 'img/bike5.png' */
        }
    );

    extraMarkers[myID] = marker300;

    var infowindow300 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        {
            content: '<div style="width: 200px;">Test 300 - <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a></div>'
        }
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker300, 
        'click', 
        function()
        {
            infowindow300.open(map, marker300);
        }
    );
}

$('#mapall').change(
    function()
    {
        var myID = $(this).attr('id');

        if($('#mapall').attr('checked'))
        {
            showOverlays(myID);
        }
        else
        {
            clearOverlays(myID);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you have single marker on map then use marker.setMap(null);
if Multiple marker make an array for marker
 markersArray.push(marker);
 if (markersArray) {
     for (i in markersArray) { 
             markersArray[i].setMap(null); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
marker300.setMap(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your marker was not visible outside of `showOverlays()` function. Error was reported in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: marker300 is not defined
```

Minimum change is to define `marker300` as global:

```
var map;
var marker300;
```

and delete marker in

```
function clearOverlays() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker300, 'click');
    marker300.setMap(null);
}
```

and remove `var` in front of variable marker300 in function `showOverlays()`

See [example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8D7y/3/)

If you want to have several markers than you will have to follow solution from user *Merianos Nikos*